# useEffect infinite loop with GraphQL fetch

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch

I am writing a simple react hook that fetches some data form a GraphQL endpoint, stores the result in a state and returns `[fetched-data, true]` when the data is fetched or `[null, false]` when there is no data so you can use it in components like `const [data, loaded] = useGraphql({ query, variables }); return loaded ? data : 'loading'`.

The problem I am experiencing is that if I declare the optional variables property of the argument object, the hook causes an infinite useEffect loop. If I omit the variables argument, everything works fine.

```
export default function useGraphql({ query, variables, token }: QueryArgs) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        const init: RequestInit = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                [token && 'Authorization']: token && `bearer ${token}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query, variables
            })
        }

        try {
            const response: Response = await fetch('/graphql', init)

            const parsed = await response.json()

            setData(parsed.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)

            setData(null)
        }
    }, [query, variables, token]) // if I remove variables from the array here, this doesn't cause a loop anymore

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true

        if (mounted) {
            fetchData()
        }

        return () => {
            mounted = false

            setData(null)
        }
    }, [fetchData])

    if (data) {
        for (const prop in data) {
            return [data[prop], true]

            break;
        }
    }

    return [null, false]
}
```

of course I am using this hook like this in a component:

```
const [data, loaded] = useGraphql({ 
        query: `query ($email: String!) {
            singleUser(email: $email) {
                username
                email
            }
        }`,
        variables: {
            email: "user1@project" // if I put variables like this, the loop occurs. If I hardcode the variables in the query, there is no loop.
        }
    })

    return <span> {loaded ? data.email : 'loading'} </span>
```

I really don't understand why putting variables is causing infinite rerenders. How is `variables` argument changing the `fetchData` function?

Comment: I want to point out I am aware that using an empty array for useEffect solves the problem, my question is WHY using `variables` as argument causes this re-render

Comment: Could it be the reference for `variables` that's changing even though variables.email doesn't? 
Try putting `variables.email` in the dependency array instead and there is a chance you avoid the loop.

Comment: @Rikku is correct. Except that you still need `variables` as a dependency of fetchData. Because useGraphql will run the api fetch every time the reference for variables is updated (ie, when a new variables object is created on every render), you will have to control the reference for variables. Try `const variables = useMemo(() => ({email: userEmail}), [userEmail])`. Or use no dependencies if it never updates.

Comment: That is right, it's the object reference that's changing. How could I avoid that? The solution with `useMemo` works, but I'd like to implement it inside the hook rather than using It every time I call the hook, and didn't find a way to do it. I've tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variables))` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution for now:

instead of passing the plain variables object, I check if it has changed with the following code and return the result as a string.

```
function updateObj(obj: object): string {
    let object: string = JSON.stringify(obj)

    if (object !== JSON.stringify(obj)) {
        object = JSON.stringify(obj)
    }

    return object
}
```

so in my `useGraphql` hook I use it like:

```
const updatedVariables = updateObj(variables)
```

and it is doing its job. I've tried to return an object instead of a stringified one but then the parsed result (with `JSON.parse()`) is still causing the loop